# Generating a big matrix - Mathematica won't do it

Tags: matrix, export

I already posted a similar problem, but this one is different.
I want to create and export a $(n\times n)$-Matrix and later on implement it again. My code works and for $(8000\times8000)$ my Matrix will be created. If I want to increase the number ,i.e. speaking of $10. 000\times10.000$ or even $50.000\times50.000$ Mathematica won't do the job - and I don't even know why. The calculation just stops without a notification, the matrix won't be exported.

I'll post my code below. $f[t]$ is a (yet) unknown function (My Matrix will depend on it) and $N2$ denotes the dimension of my matrix ($N2$ has to be even). The matrix I want to export is MatrixF[N2] depending on $N2$. :

```
SetDirectory[NotebookDirectory[]];
N2 = 10000;
F = Table[q[i, j], {i, N2}, {j, N2}];

Do[
  q[i, i + 1] = 1;
  q[i + 1, i + 2] = 1;
  q[i + 1, i + 1] = 2/3 h^2 f[i - i];
  q[i, i] = h^2 f[i - i];
  q[i + 1, i] = 8/3 h^2 f[1] - 1;
  q[i, i - 1] = 2 h^2 f[1] - 1;

  Do[
     q[j + 1, j - i + 1 - 2] = 8/3 h^2 f[i + 2];
     q[j, j - i - 2] = 2 h^2 f[i + 2];
     q[j + 1, j + 1 - i - 1] = 4/3 h^2 f[i + 1];
     q[j, j - i - 1] = 2 h^2 f[i + 1];
     , {j, 1, N2, 2}
                     ];

     , {i, 1, N2 - 1, 2}  ];






 q[N2, N2 - 1] = 8/3 h^2 f[1] - 4;
 q[N2, N2 - 2] = 1 + 4/3 h^2 f[2];
 q[N2, N2] = 2/3 h^2 f[0] + 3;



 MatrixF[N2] = LowerTriangularize[F, 1];


 Export["MatrixF" <> ToString[N2] <> ".m", MatrixF[N2]]
```

If I set N2=10 or 8000 it will work.
Thanks already for your help!

Comment: If you're able to do this with numerics it'll be fast--especially if you use `Compile`. If you can't... well I can't see a way around either the memory or speed issues.

Comment: Storing a dense 50000 x 50000 matrix of `Real`s needs `N[8 50000 50000/2^20]` MegaByte. That's around 19 GB that your machine might not have at the ready. Storing symbols in the matrix will blow it up considerably more (in your case: by a factor of 20 or so). This should tell you that you are doing something really wrong, conceptually.

Comment: Thanks! I don't know anything about storage space/memory usage, so I'll just try to implement the function first....perhaps that'll work.

Comment: Are you interested in the matrix itself or only in its action of a vector? The latter might be implementable much less memory demanding...

Comment: filling a dense matrix with symbolic expressions is gonna be expensive, and it seems like you indirect through other expressions too.

Comment: Consider to use `SparseArray` and `Band`, if one can figure out the relation between the entries and the positions.